# Induction and Recursion Proof using Catalan Numbers

Tags: induction, recursion

Note that a product 
[image]
may be parenthesized in two different ways:  [image] and [image]. Similarly, there are several different ways to parenthesize [image]. Two such ways are [image] and [image]. Let [image] be the number of different ways to parenthesize the product [image]. Show that if [image], then

[image]

for all integers [image].

Keep in mind that the sequence [image] is the same as the sequence of Catalan numbers.

I am entirely lost. Please can someone offer some hint or direction of where to begin? I humbly thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is pretty simple: $k$-th summand in $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P_k P_{n-k}$ corresponds to the number of parenthesizations of the product $x_1 \cdots x_n$ like this: $(x_1 \cdots x_k)\cdot(x_{k+1} \cdots x_n)$. There are $P_k$ ways to parenthesize the first parenthese, and $P_{n-k}$ to parenthesize the other, so they both give $P_k P_{n-k}$. Try to proceed from here yourself.